# ipv6 local connection

Tags: ubuntu, routing, ipv6

So I have an ubuntu 10.04 router that is tunneling ipv6 to hurricane electric. It has perfectly fine ipv6 connectivity. My problem is that I want to have my ubuntu 10.04 machine behind it be able to connect (at least to the router, then out it) via ipv6. How do I do this?

info:

I set up ipv6 using:

```
    ifconfig sit0 up
    ifconfig sit0 inet6 tunnel ::a.b.c.d
    ifconfig sit1 up
    ifconfig sit1 inet6 add 2001:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::2/64
    route -A inet6 add ::/0 dev sit1
```

ifconfig on router:

```
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:55:f9:7a:c1  
            inet addr:192.168.1.x  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::202:55ff:fef9:7ac1/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:10813 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:11016 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:3081850 (3.0 MB)  TX bytes:1399231 (1.3 MB)

  eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:cd:19:37:e1  
            inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::20a:cdff:fe19:37e1/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:5209 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:4147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:724340 (724.3 KB)  TX bytes:2392799 (2.3 MB)
            Interrupt:16 Base address:0x3000 

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
            inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
            inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
            UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
            RX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
            RX bytes:7413 (7.4 KB)  TX bytes:7413 (7.4 KB)

  sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
            inet6 addr: ::192.168.1.x/96 Scope:Compat
            inet6 addr: ::127.0.0.1/96 Scope:Unknown
            inet6 addr: ::10.0.0.1/96 Scope:Compat
            UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  sit1      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
            inet6 addr: fe80::c0a8:14b/64 Scope:Link
            inet6 addr: 2001:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::2/64 Scope:Global
            inet6 addr: fe80::a00:1/64 Scope:Link
            UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
            RX packets:6034 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:6103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
            RX bytes:500568 (500.5 KB)  TX bytes:482704 (482.7 KB)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

edit:

# ip -6 route show

```
    ::/96 via :: dev sit0  metric 256  mtu 1480 advmss 1420 hoplimit 0
    2001:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::/64 via :: dev sit1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 advmss 1420 hoplimit 0
    fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
    fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
    fe80::/64 via :: dev sit1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1480 advmss 1420 hoplimit 0
    default dev sit1  metric 1  mtu 1480 advmss 1420 hoplimit 0
```

# ip -6 addr show

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
        inet6 fe80::202:55ff:fef9:7ac1/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
        inet6 fe80::20a:cdff:fe19:37e1/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    5: sit0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 
        inet6 ::10.0.0.1/96 scope global 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::192.168.1.x/96 scope global 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::127.0.0.1/96 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    6: sit1: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 
        inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::2/64 scope global 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::a00:1/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::c0a8:14b/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: please post `ip -6 route show` and `ip -6 addr show`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to get a routed /48 subnet from Hurricane, because what you have now is only for the system where you terminate your tunnel  Then you can use one of the /64's from your /48 on your ethernet. Enable IPv6 forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf and start radvd on the ethernet so the rest of the network knows about your router/system. Please be aware that you won't have a firewall for IPv6 yet!

Comment: Actually the default /64 should be enough for one LAN. The tunnel interface will use the tunnel PtP /64.

Comment: A /64 is the size you need for each link. Hurricane uses a /64 for the PtP link and they assign a /48 for further networks. You can't use the /64 of the PtP link on your LAN.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But they provide a routed /64 by default, *in addition to* the PtP /64. The routed /64 is enough for one LAN. For several LANs you need to request the /48 and split it up to /64s.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to send IPv6 Router Advertisement packets for the client device to figure it out, unless it's manually configured.  (is it?)

The `radvd` package is what you'll want to send RAs.

Comment: I already tried that using https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6#Configure%20your%20Ubuntu%20box%20as%20a%20IPv6%20router but it didn't work when i set my ubuntu desktop to try to get an ipv6 address automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to read the man pages to cut'n'paste the exact syntax for you, but it is the same as with IPv4 and the same on any UNIX-like operating system:

- Enable IPv6 forwarding on the gw.
- Enable your IPv6 uplink with he.net with your PtP /64 address on the gw.
- Configure your LAN network interface on the gw with a static IPv6 address from your **routed** /64 space.
- Configure machines in your LAN (either static route to your gw or run **radvd** on the gw).